# How to get drop shadow to always face down on rotating object

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently making a working clock with css and javascript, and I need to have drop shadows on it. currently the drop shadow is always to one side of the hand and I need it to always be facing downward. I can't share the exact code, but this codepen is very similar: https://codepen.io/ilyasw/pen/PddVja

Here is the relevant

HTML

```
  <img src="media/hour-hand.png" class="hourHand hand" />
  <img src="media/second-hand.png" class="secondHand hand" />
  <img src="media/minute-hand.png" class="minuteHand hand" />
  <img src="media/small-second-hand.png" class="smallSecondHand hand">
```

CSS

```
    .hand {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px black);
    height: 30vmin;
  }

  .hourHand {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(55deg);
  }

  .minuteHand {
    z-index: 3;
    transform: translate(-50.5%, -50%) rotate(-51.7deg);
  }

  .secondHand {
    z-index: 4;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(140deg);
  }

  .smallSecondHand {
    left: calc(50% - 10vmin + 2px);
    height: 12vmin;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

JS

```
   setInterval("clock()", 10);

function clock() {
    let dt = new Date(),
        hr = dt.getHours(),
        min = dt.getMinutes(),
        sec = dt.getSeconds(),
        msec = dt.getMilliseconds(),
        hrDeg = 55 + (hr * 30) + (min * 30/60),
        minDeg = -51.7 + (min * 6) + (sec * 6/60),
        secDeg = (sec * 6) + (6 * msec/1000),
        hrHand = document.querySelector('.hourHand'),
        minHand = document.querySelector('.minuteHand'),
        secHand = document.querySelector('.smallSecondHand'),
        dayCell = document.querySelector('p');
    
    hrHand.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(" + hrDeg + "deg)";
    minHand.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(" + minDeg + "deg)";
    secHand.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(" + secDeg + "deg)";

}
```

The only real difference is that I'm using a drop shadow because the hands are PNG's not css objects. Is there any reasonable way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: you must include some relevant code that we can help you

Comment: @לבנימלכה it's all included in the codepen that's linked

Comment: I know but in future if this link will break people will not be able to see the code

Comment: @לבנימלכה It's added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sine and cosine to find the offset of the boxshadow.

```
var d2rFactor = Math.PI / 180; //convert degrees to radians
var shadowAngle = 45; // what angle the shadow should have compared to line
var shadowOffset = 10; // distance

function rotateLine(target, deg) {
  var r = (shadowAngle - deg) * g2rFactor; // find the angle that the shadow should have to counter to rotation of the line.
  var x = Math.cos(r)*shadowOffset;
  var y = Math.sin(r)*shadowOffset;
  
  target.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;
  target.style.boxShadow = `${x}px ${y}px 5px black`;
}
```

Here is a test to show its working https://codepen.io/tommyka/pen/vYmQbbd

Comment: this looks great! I don't understand all of it, but I will implement it in the morning and see if I can get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: @TheAndersMan If you are interested in animation or just graphics programming in general you should understand the unit circle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1m9p9iubMLU. Note that you can just google "unit circle" to get a deeper understanding of sin and cos functions however the Khan academy video I linked is a good introduction

Answer (score 0):

If the light is coming from above then you need to sense when a hand goes through a vertical position (6 or 12 o'clock) and set the style of the hand to have the correct box shadow.

You could use the box shadow you have but above not below the image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom properties as the box-shadow offset values, and manipulate it with JavaScript according to the position of the hands. It's possible to make this very fine grained with tiny updates for every tick, or set it to just adjust CSS when the hands change from a vertical to a horizontal position:

```css
    :root {
      --clockHandShadowHorizontalOffset: 0;
      --clockHandShadowVerticalOffset: 4px;
    }

    .clockhandshadow {
      box-shadow: var(--clockHandShadowHorizontalOffset) var(--clockHandShadowVerticalOffset) 6px #0000004a;
    }
```

Sketch for the JS part:

```js
    let root = document.documentElement;

    const rotateBoxShadow = ( degree ) => {

      let horizontalOffset, verticalOffset
      // Maybe reuse the function that makes hands move to calculate values?
      horizontalOffset = ... + 'px'
      verticalOffset = ... + 'px'
      
      // Update CSS
      root.style.setProperty('--clockHandShadowHorizontalOffset', horizontalOffset);
      root.style.setProperty('--clockHandShadowVerticalOffset, verticalOffset);
    }

    // Get a dynamic value for hand rotation somehow

    rotateBoxShadow(rotation)
```